# table cell drawing on same position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have to populate numbers of row. when i uses

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

this line, after scrolling to some rows it redrawing rows on same position.see below screen
[image]

if i make cell nil i.e.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
```

then works fine,but it takes unexpecedly more memory. now my question is why its happening.

> what is the relation of making cell nil to redrawing on same position?

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    UIButton *questionButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    questionButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    questionButton.tag=indexPath.row+1;

    [questionButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];

    UIImageView *statusImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190,25,23,23)];

    NSString *statusImageName=[[NSString  alloc]init];
    statusImageName=@"Right";
    [statusImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:statusImageName]];
    [questionButton addSubview:statusImageView];

    if(indexPath.row%2==0)
    {
        [questionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopicsbarLeft"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [questionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopicsbarLetSelected"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        CGRect topicButtonFrame=CGRectMake(0, 10, 250, 70);
        questionButton.frame=topicButtonFrame;



        NSLog(@"Even Rows =%d",indexPath.row);

        NSString *questionLabel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Question %d :",indexPath.row+1];
        [questionButton setTitle:questionLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //questionButton.titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;

        [questionButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    }
    else
    {
        [questionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopicsbarRight"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [questionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopicsbarRightSelected"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        CGRect topicButtonFrame=CGRectMake(100, 10, 250, 70);
        questionButton.frame=topicButtonFrame;


        NSString *questionLabel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"     Question %d :",indexPath.row+1];
        [questionButton setTitle:questionLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        questionButton.titleLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;
        [cell addSubview:questionButton];

    }

    [cell addSubview:questionButton];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The `UITableViewCell` is reused again and again in `UITableView` so you need to instantiate it when it becomes nil.

Comment: Can you put some more code from your UITableView delegate methods?

Comment: Im wondering why this question is being down voted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView scrolling and redraw issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009990/uitableview-scrolling-and-redraw-issue)

Comment: my question is different,plz read carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is to use less memory.  If the screen can fit 4 or 5 table cells, then with reuse you only need to have 4 or 5 table cells allocated in memory even if the table has 1000 entries.

So when you do this `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` and it returns an old cell to reuse. It is not a new cell instance. It contains UI elements of the cell initialised to the old data. To display it again you need to reset all the UI elements and put in your new values.

The second way when you put `UITableViewCell *cell = nil;` there is no reuse. There is no advantage in the second way over just using an array of table cells. If your table has 1000 entries then you will have 1000 cells allocated in memory. If you are going to do that you would put them in an array and just index the array with the row number and return the cell. This should explain your spike in memory usage as it is not reusing any cell instance.

For small tables with fixed cells second solution may be an reasonable solution, for dynamic or large tables reusing is the best way to go...

**UPDATE:** since you have asked for some code. Also note that you are doing 2 types of rending depending on odd or even. So the cell that comes out of `reuse` might be odd when you want to show even numbered question. In that case you would need to reset the cell just after the cell is got (either from reuse or created new) and let  your normal logic flow through...

```
    [questionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"]];
    [questionButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    CGRect topicButtonFrame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 70);
    questionButton.frame=topicButtonFrame;
```

Comment: how i can reset all UI element

Comment: by reset I mean bring the reused `UITableViewCell` to the state to which it would have been when it is newly created. i.e. reset any `UIlabels` or reposition any UIElements or set `UIImageView` to some default image. Best way to do this is see what UI elements you are using in you UITableViewCell and set them back to some default values. Did I understand your Question right? when you were using `reuse` you are seeing some old values in the reused cells?

Comment: you are absolutely correct, can u tell me how to reset these UI elements by help of some code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
        [cell addSubview:questionButton];
    }
    [cell addSubview:questionButton];
```

You are adding the questionButton twice. Please remove one in else section and try.

**Update :**

Can you try this just for the confirmation what is the problem:

```
if(indexPath.row%2==0)
{
    UIButton *questionButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    questionButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    questionButton.tag=indexPath.row+1;

    [questionButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];

    UIImageView *statusImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190,25,23,23)];

    NSString *statusImageName=[[NSString  alloc]init];
    statusImageName=@"Right";
    [statusImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:statusImageName]];
    [questionButton addSubview:statusImageView];
    [questionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopicsbarLeft"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [questionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopicsbarLetSelected"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    CGRect topicButtonFrame=CGRectMake(0, 10, 250, 70);
    questionButton.frame=topicButtonFrame;

    NSString *questionLabel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Question %d :",indexPath.row+1];
    [questionButton setTitle:questionLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //questionButton.titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    [questionButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [cell addSubview:questionButton];
}
else
{
    UIButton *questionButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    questionButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    questionButton.tag=indexPath.row+1;

    [questionButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];

    UIImageView *statusImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190,25,23,23)];

    NSString *statusImageName=[[NSString  alloc]init];
    statusImageName=@"Right";
    [statusImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:statusImageName]];
    [questionButton addSubview:statusImageView];
    [questionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopicsbarRight"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [questionButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopicsbarRightSelected"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    CGRect topicButtonFrame=CGRectMake(100, 10, 250, 70);
    questionButton.frame=topicButtonFrame;


    NSString *questionLabel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"     Question %d :",indexPath.row+1];
    [questionButton setTitle:questionLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    questionButton.titleLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;
    [cell addSubview:questionButton];

}
```

Comment: yeah,i made changes,even it is giving same redraw problem

Comment: I think you need to release the questionButton.
UIButton *questionButton=[[[UIButton alloc] init] autorelease];