# Tableview cells misplaced upon scrolling

Tags: ios, tableview

Im creating a tableview. In the cellforrowatindexpath method i create a label and a imageview. Everything works well till here. But the cells are misplaced upon scrolling the tableview. this is the code i used:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NameLabel = [UILabel new];
    NameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(143, 8, 95, 25);
    NameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BBCNassim" size:16.0];
    //NameLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    NameLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:NameLabel];

    IconLabel = [UIImageView new];
    IconLabel.frame = CGRectMake(245, 8, 24, 24);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:IconLabel];
}

if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    [NameLabel setText:[self.menuItemsFirst objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [IconLabel setImage:[self.menuImgsFirst objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
if (indexPath.section == 1)
{
    [NameLabel setText:[self.menuItemsSecond objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [IconLabel setImage:[self.menuImgsSecond objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
if (indexPath.section == 2)
{
    [NameLabel setText:[self.menuItemsThird objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [IconLabel setImage:[self.menuImgsThird objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by misplaced??

Comment: The cells move and replace each other!

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView scrolling and redraw issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009990/uitableview-scrolling-and-redraw-issue)

Comment: try using custom cells instead..

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil)
   {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   }

      NameLabel = [UILabel new];
      NameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(143, 8, 95, 25);
      NameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BBCNassim" size:16.0];
      //NameLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
      NameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
      NameLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:NameLabel];

      IconLabel = [UIImageView new];
      IconLabel.frame = CGRectMake(245, 8, 24, 24);
      [cell.contentView addSubview:IconLabel];

      if (indexPath.section == 0)
      {
        [NameLabel setText:[self.menuItemsFirst objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [IconLabel setImage:[self.menuImgsFirst objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      }
      if (indexPath.section == 1)
      {
        [NameLabel setText:[self.menuItemsSecond objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [IconLabel setImage:[self.menuImgsSecond objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      }
      if (indexPath.section == 2)
      {
        [NameLabel setText:[self.menuItemsThird objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [IconLabel setImage:[self.menuImgsThird objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      }

 return cell;
}
```

Comment: still the same thing! The cells arnt in their place.

Comment: can you add a screen shot of your output?

Comment: is it table cell rendering problem or the values are not in proper cell? if its the second case you need to check your arrays. I am even sure that arrays contain what they need to contain and your logic needs a change. If you clearly explain about the result your expecting, We can give you a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that your `NameLabel` and `IconLabel` are global variables. And all the different sets of data for each cell are overwriting the same elements.

You should create the labels locally in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and add them to each cell.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to request a reusable cell in table view is:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
        dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
                             forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

... so add `forIndexPath:indexPath`